# Downloading a file through an UWP application in JavaScript and Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, uwp

I have a progressive application where the front-end is developed in Angular. In order to compile and ship it as an UWP application, I created UWP javascript project where the index.html has an iframe that points to my local server (angular). To sum up, it is just a mirror to my angular project.

```
<body id="body" class="win-type-body">
    <iframe id="content" width="100%" height="100%" src="http://127.0.0.1:4200"></iframe>
</body>
```

In this web application, I have created a button (that on click calls onSave() method) that downloads a text or a picture (as you wish).

```
onSave() {
    console.log('onSave');
    let link = document.createElement('a');
    link.download = 'hello.txt';

    let blob = new Blob(["Hello, world!"], {type: "text/plain;charset=utf-8"});
    link.href = URL.createObjectURL(blob)
    link.click();

    URL.revokeObjectURL(link.href);
}
```

When I click the button (using the browser), the download window is displayed and I can save the file wherever I want (nothing odd here, just downloading a file).

However, when I compile the application through UWP, and I click the download button, I don't get the behavior I want. The application just shows the text on the screen (iframe), and the download window is not shown. Do you guys have faced this problem any time? Is there any way to do this on a Windows UWP application?

Cheers.

Comment: To save file from a JavaScript UWP app, you have to use UWP save file API but not web API. Here for your app actually I recommend that you use PWA directly: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps

Comment: I kind get that, but how do I do this with a front-end running within Angular. How do I access this API.

Comment: Sorry Can I understand that what is your choice. PWA or WinJS UWP project? If PWA, you can refer to here:https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/progressive-web-apps/windows-features#find-windows-runtime-winrt-apis

Comment: I didn't metion it, I am sorry. It is a WinJS UWP project.

Comment: For a WinJS UWP project, please see this demo https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/FilePicker/js When you get the file, you can then use filepicker to save your file to any place that you want to save. It will popup a picker window for you.